# cordova media with compression not create file

Tags: android, cordova, audio, plugins, cordova-plugins

I work for some time with the cordova-media-plugin for recording audio files on mobile. It works well. However the poor audio quality android (amr) and the excessive weight of the wav file (ios), leads me to use [this compression plugin in m4a](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-media-with-compression).

But on android, no error occurs on the creation of the record, but a problem arises when you have recovered the file, it does not exist. The path that was operating on the cordova-media-plugin returns empty. I can not find solutions or similar problems. The rest github does not included the problems.

Any solution for compression ?

Thks